# Unpaired comparison of groups with unknown but equal sizes and unequal variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have computed confidence intervals for the R-squared performance of different PGS models (via r2redux, as described in [this paper](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.06.08.495250v1.full)) and now I wish to conduct statistical significance tests of their differences.

I understand the means and standard errors can be calculated by assuming that the 95% confidence interval was obtained as the values 1.96×SE either side of the mean, but this would not allow computing sample sizes.

Are there are any t-tests for unequal variances and unknown samples sizes?

Comment: Can you please (by editing your post, not only as a comment?) tell us what is PGS?